# Entity Framework Core zero-or-one to zero-or-one relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Given these classes:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int? BId {get; set;}
    public B B {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int? AId {get; set;}
    public A A {get; set;} 
}
```

Then with Fluent API

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
                .HasOne(a => a.B)
                .WithOne(b => b.A)
                .HasForeignKey<A>(a => a.BId);
```

When creating objects and add them to database, things look like following in the corresponding tables:

- [A].BId is set
- [B].AId = null

When I retrieve data using EF Core:

- A.B is set, A.BId is set
- B.A is set, but **B.AId is null**.

What should I do to have B.AId set as well?

Comment: Why `one-to-zero` or `one-to-one` in both end? Which one is your principal entity and which one is your dependent entity? Please explain this. It would be easy to guess what you actually need.

Comment: They are independent. Each can exist without the other,. When they both exist, an A can only be associated with a B and same B can only be associated with initial A.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Then what's wrong with your current configuration?

Comment: Can you add your insert operation code here please!

Comment: ```A a = new A() { B = new B()} ``` After adding a to context and saving changes, in A table BId is set, but in B table AId is null.    And also when retrieving data  dbContext.As.Include(a=>a.B)   I get a.B.A is set, but a.B.AId is null .

Comment: Because you have not set the AId in B object! Code is working as expected. Nothing wrong here.

Comment: OK, but at time of object creation that id is unkown, and I thought EF can take care of it. The same as for BId. However how can EF set A in a.B.A, but doesn't set AId in a.B.AId ?   or in the simplier case b.A is set, but b.AId is not set?

Comment: EF taking care of BId because you assigning value to the navigation property.

Comment: OK, but what can I do to get AId set as well?

Comment: Why do you need to ser AId to B as you are already connected to A from B using BId? May are getting one-one-one relationship wrong!

Comment: When I have some B at hand I want to see its AId. I believe it is absolutely OK to navigate from both ends. Both from A to B and from B to A. And this from both object and ids perspective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These `0..1 : 0..1` relations are usually defined between entities of which none is an obvious principal entity. I like the example of cars and drivers, which is a bit more imaginable than A and B.

The model you're after looks like this:

[image: OneToOneWithKeys]

There are two mutual foreign keys, both of which have a unique index to enforce 1:1 at the database level.

The `HasOne - WithOne` combi can't be used here, because that always requires a `HasForeignKey` instruction to tell which entity is principal. This also configures only one field as foreign key. In your example, `B.AId` is just a regular field. If you don't give it a value, EF won't either.

The mapping of the above model is a bit more cumbersome than `HasOne - WithOne`:

```
var carEtb = modelBuilder.Entity<Car>();
var driverEtb = modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>();

carEtb.HasOne(c => c.Driver).WithMany();
carEtb.HasIndex(c => c.DriverID).IsUnique();

driverEtb.HasOne(d => d.Car).WithMany();
driverEtb.HasIndex(c => c.CarID).IsUnique();
```

So there are two 0..1:n association that are made unique by indexes on the foreign keys.

Which creates the following database model:

```sql
  CREATE TABLE [Drivers] (
      [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
      [Name] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [CarID] int NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_Drivers] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
  );

  CREATE TABLE [Cars] (
      [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
      [Brand] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [Type] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [DriverID] int NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_Cars] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]),
      CONSTRAINT [FK_Cars_Drivers_DriverID] FOREIGN KEY ([DriverID])
          REFERENCES [Drivers] ([ID]) ON DELETE NO ACTION
  );

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Cars_DriverID] ON [Cars] ([DriverID])
      WHERE [DriverID] IS NOT NULL;


  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Drivers_CarID] ON [Drivers] ([CarID])
      WHERE [CarID] IS NOT NULL;

  ALTER TABLE [Drivers] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Drivers_Cars_CarID] FOREIGN KEY ([CarID])
      REFERENCES [Cars] ([ID]) ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

It creates two nullable foreign keys both indexed by a unique *filtered* index. Perfect!

But...

EF doesn't see this as a bidirectional one-on-one relationship. And rightly so. The two FKs are just that, two independent FKs. However, in view of data integrity the relationship should be established by both ends: if a driver claims a car (sets `driver.CarID`), the car should also be attached to the driver (set `car.DriverID`), otherwise another driver could be connected to it.

When existing car and drivers are coupled a little helper method could be used, for example in `Car`:

```cs
public void SetDriver(Driver driver)
{
    Driver = driver;
    driver.Car = this;
}
```

However, when both a `Car` and `Driver` are created *and* associated in one process, this is clumsy. EF will throw an `InvalidOperationException`:

> Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'Car [Added] <- Car { 'CarID' } Driver [Added] <- Driver { 'DriverID' } Car [Added]'.

Which means: one of the FKs can be be set at once, but the other one can only be set after saving the data.  That requires two `SaveChanges` calls enclosed by a transaction in a pretty imperative piece of code:

```cs
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    using (var t = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var jag = new Car { Brand = "Jaguar", Type = "E" };
        var peter = new Driver { Name = "Peter Sellers", Car = jag };

        db.Drivers.Add(peter);

        db.SaveChanges();

        jag.Driver = peter;

        db.SaveChanges();
        t.Commit();
    }
}
```

#### Alternative: junction table

So now the reason why I go to these lengths explaining all this: in my opinion, `0..1 : 0..1` associations should be modeled by a junction table with unique foreign keys:

[image: OntToOneJunction]

By using a junction table -

1. The association can be established in an atomic operation instead of an error-prone operation of setting two foreign keys.
2. The entities themselves are independent: they don't have foreign keys they don't really need to fulfill their role.

This model can be implemented by this class model:

```cs
public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public CarDriver CarDriver { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public Driver()
    { }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CarDriver CarDriver { get; set; }
}

public class CarDriver
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public int DriverID { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var carDriverEtb = modelBuilder.Entity<CarDriver>();
    carDriverEtb.HasKey(cd => new { cd.CarID, cd.DriverID });
    carDriverEtb.HasIndex(cd => cd.CarID).IsUnique();
    carDriverEtb.HasIndex(cd => cd.DriverID).IsUnique();
}
```

Now creating drivers and cars *and* their associations can easily be done in one `SaveChanges` call:

```cs
using (var db = new MyContext(connectionString))
{
    var ford = new Car { Brand = "Ford", Type = "Mustang" };
    var jag = new Car { Brand = "Jaguar", Type = "E" };

    var kelly = new Driver { Name = "Kelly Clarkson" };
    var peter = new Driver { Name = "Peter Sellers" };

    db.CarDrivers.Add(new CarDriver { Car = ford, Driver = kelly });
    db.CarDrivers.Add(new CarDriver { Car = jag, Driver = peter });

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The only drawback is that navigting from `Car` to `Driver` vv is a bit les convenient. Well, see for yourself which model suit you best.

Comment: Isn't making any of the ends "principal" and the other end "dependent" with single optional FK (with `SetNull` cascade option) enough for this type of relationship? The navigation would be simpler compared to explicit join entity, and the order of the CUD operations is defined.

Comment: @Ivan Ah of course, good point. I still have to get used to the new 1:1 options in EF-core. I'll see into it. My main point is that a mutually optional 1:1 relation always seem a bit weird to me business-wise, because neither of the involved entities has a clear ownership or responsibility of establishing it (otherwise there would be an obvious principal). I think in reality such associations are always a third party's responsibility, f.e. a rental contract with begin and end date etc.), i.e. as an entity in it own right that, in fact, *is* the association.

Answer (score 0):

In EFCore 3.1 you can do one to zero relation like this:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DriverId { get; set; }
        
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Car Driver { get; set; }
}
```

in your dbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
        .HasOne(x => x.Driver)
        .WithOne(x => x.Car)
        .HasForeignKey<Car>(x => x.DriverId);
}
```

Then you can include:

driver from car

```
dbContext.Driver.Inclide(x => x.Car)...
```

car from driver

```
dbContext.Car.Inclide(x => x.Driver)...
```