# What is the best method for Required-to-Optional Relationship (One-to–Zero-or-One) in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have implemented the project of EntityFramework 6 into EntityFramework Core. I have to do migrate EF6 relationship pattern into EF core .
I found some references below:

1. [Entity Framework Core zero-or-one to zero-or-one relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497784/entity-framework-core-zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one-relation)

but didn't get any ideas on required-optional relationship in EF-Core.

**Sample1.cs:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<StudentAddress>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Student)
                .WithOptional(x => x.StudentAddress);
}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public virtual StudentAddress StudentAddress { get; set; }
}

public class StudentAddress
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample2.cs:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<StudentAddress>()
                .HasKey(sa => sa.StudentId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<StudentAddress>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Student)
                .WithOptional(x => x.StudentAddress);
}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public virtual StudentAddress StudentAddress { get; set; }
}

public class StudentAddress
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Kindly someone help me that how to do that in EF-Core using fluent api

Comment: Many-to-Many was introduced in EF Core 5.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Answer (score 2):

You can try this (Ref.: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#required-and-optional-relationships)):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<StudentAddress>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Student)
                .WithOne(x => x.StudentAddress).IsRequired(false);
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a FK `StudentAddressId` in your `Student` Model an have the type be nullable `int?`

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    
    // This is the FK for StudentAddress.
    // Make it int? (nullable) if StudentAddress is optional
    public int? StudentAddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual StudentAddress StudentAddress { get; set; }
}

public class StudentAddress
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Since the FK is nullable, you don't need the IsRequired(false)
    modelBuilder.Entity<StudentAddress>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Student)
                .WithOne(x => x.StudentAddress);
}
```

Comment: If Haskey specified in configuration what we do like "modelBuilder.Entity<StudentAddress>().HasKey(sa => sa.StudentId)". In the StudentAddress model has one more property as "public int StudentId { get; set; }";

Comment: @KarthicG I am sorry could not understand what you meant in that comment

Comment: I have edited my question with 2 samples. your answer is helpful for sample1.cs. I need to answer for sample2.cs if they used HasKey() method.

Comment: @KarthicG I think you are mixing up stuff. Why do you wanna make StudentId the PK in the StudentAddress table? StudentAddress should have StudentAddressId as PK, and perhaps StudentId as FK

Comment: This is the one of my scenario for sample2.cs, so asked what is expected result in EF core?