# How do I create a One-to-One mapping without using a foreign key constraint?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, one-to-one, ef-fluent-api

**Problem** - I need to create some type of mapping between 2 entities with property "SourceTransactionId", where either entity can be added to the db first, before the other, but still be able to query like below.

**What I want**: Display transfers to sender or receiver (depending on who's requesting to see their transfers) and its associated StripePayment data:

```
var transfers = _dbContext.StripeTransfers.Select(p => new {
   TransferAmount = p.StripePayment.Amount,
   TransferDate = p.DateCreated,
   Sender = p.StripePayment.Sender.UserName,
   Receiver = p.StripePayment.Receiver.UserName
}).Where(p => p.StripePayment.Sender.Id == userId || p.StripePayment.Receiver.Id == userId)
.ToListAsync();
```

**Requirement** - I don't know which entity will be created first as StripeTransfer is being created from a webhook that might be received before I can create the StripePayment entity, so either row should be capable of being added before the other one.

Here is my code:

```
public class StripePayment
{
    // primary key
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SourceTransactionId { get; set; }
    public StripeTransfer StripeTransfer { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int SenderId { get; set; }
    public User Sender { get; set; }
    public int ReceiverId { get; set; }
    public User Receiver { get; set; }
}

public class StripeTransfer
{
    // primary key
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SourceTransactionId { get; set; }
    public StripePayment StripePayment { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

**What I tried** - I tried adding a foreign key constraint, but this won't allow me to add a StripeTransfer before there is a StripePayment created.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StripePayment>()
            .HasOne<StripeTransfer>(t => t.StripeTransfer)
            .WithOne(t => t.StripePayment)
            .HasPrincipalKey<StripePayment>(p => p.SourceTransactionId)
            .HasForeignKey<StripeTransfer>(t => t.SourceTransactionId)
            .IsRequired(false);
```

Error received when trying to add a StripeTransfer before a StripePayment:

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_StripeTransfers_StripePayments_SourceTransactionId". The conflict occurred in database "yogabandy-database-dev", table "dbo.StripePayments", column 'LatestChargeId'.\nThe statement has been terminated."

Comment: Because you already have **Id** in your "BaseEntity", and you want to add _ForeignKey_ with another property. so, I think, you should use **PrincipalKey**.

Comment: Can only be done by a junction table, like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54533596/861716.

Comment: @Gert Arnold Hi Gert. In your link there is a Car, Driver and CarDriver. Would I be able to use the "SourceTransactionId" from my example as the CarId and DriverId? Also keep in mind that I wouldn't be creating a "Car" and "Driver" at the same time. They would be created at different times, so 1 of the 2 columns in "CardDriver" will be null until the other entity gets created.

Comment: It is possible if both `SourceTransactionId` properties (fields) are not nullable and unique, i.e. they should serve as alternate keys.

Comment: OK, I thought is was a nice challenge and posted an answer. It all depends on the `SourceTransactionId` fields being unique and not nullable.

Comment: Hi Gert. I'm not 100% sure SourceTransactionId is unique, but I would assume it is. It's coming from Stripe when I create a payment (charge someone's credit card) and then when Stripe transfers the money from the card to a bank account, I receive a transfer. The transfer then has the SourceTransactionId, to show which charge it was from. It allows me to link up a charge with a transfer, so I would assume it will be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special 0..1 - 0..1 relationship I never encountered so far. Let me summarize its properties so we can check that we're on the same page.

- In the database there are two independent entities (tables).
- They're connected by *key* (i.e. unique) fields that are *alternate* (non-primary) key fields.
- The connection is defined semantically by these fields having the same values in both entities.
- The connection is established logically as soon as two entities with the same key values have entered the database, in any order of arrival.

Without any relationship modelling it would be possible to query the entities by a custom `join` statement over the two connecting properties. That may be a viable solution.

But let's explore what EF can do here.

In the database, because both entities can exist without their counterparts, none can have a foreign key to the other. The relationship can only be enforced by a junction table that refers to both tables.

All that said, the good news is that EF's configuration API is expressive enough to model this.

The classes (omitting user fields):

```cs
public class StripePayment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public string SourceTransactionId { get; set; }
    public PaymentTransfer? PaymentTransfer { get; set; }
}

public class StripeTransfer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    
    public string SourceTransactionId { get; set; }
    public PaymentTransfer? PaymentTransfer { get; set; }
}
```

The junction class:

```cs
public class PaymentTransfer
{
    public string SourceTransactionId { get; set; }
    public StripePayment StripePayment { get; set; }
    public StripeTransfer StripeTransfer { get; set; }
}
```

Yes, it's only one `string` property.

The mapping configuration:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var pt = modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentTransfer>();
    pt.HasKey(e => e.SourceTransactionId);
    pt.HasOne(e => e.StripePayment).WithOne(e => e.PaymentTransfer)
        .HasPrincipalKey<StripePayment>(e => e.SourceTransactionId)
        .HasForeignKey<PaymentTransfer>(e => e.SourceTransactionId);
    pt.HasOne(e => e.StripeTransfer).WithOne(e => e.PaymentTransfer)
        .HasPrincipalKey<StripeTransfer>(e => e.SourceTransactionId)
        .HasForeignKey<PaymentTransfer>(e => e.SourceTransactionId);
}
```

Some highlights:

- EF core allows relationships to alternate keys (`SourceTransactionId` in both entities). It recognizes these keys by the `HasForeignKey` statements.
- The relationships to the junction class are 1:1, making the entire relationship 0..1-0..1.
- `PaymentTransfer.SourceTransactionId` is primary key and foreign key to both independent (principal) entities. (To me, so much function in one field is the fun part of this question).
- If EF creates a database schema from this model, both `SourceTransactionId` fields in the entity tables get unique indexes. When working database-first, make sure you create these indexes.

Now, stepping back, let's evaluate the options.

- A simple `join` statement would suffice, but manually coded joins are tedious and error-prone. Still, when tucked away in some reusable method, it may be the best option.
- A junction class, while requiring complex configuration, isn't hard to  understand and is very light-weight. It -

  - Enforces the relationship by database constraints.
  - It allows querying by navigation properties (`p.PaymentTransfer.StripePayment.Amount`, etc. in your query).
  - It is a visible, self-explanatory expression of the relationship
  - But it's *logically* redundant: if entities are *logically* connected by identical key values, w/o a junction record they're not *physically* connected.

Comment: Hi Gert. You said. "both entities can exist without their counterparts", well this is true until I populate the table with the entity, which will be done within a matter of seconds of each other. What's important is knowing that "StripeTransfer" might be populated before "StripePayment" or vise versa. This is because "StripeTransfer" is populated from a webhook coming from Stripe and I might receive it before I can populate my db with the "StripePayment" entity.

Comment: Hi Gert. Just one question. Can this be done without a junction table? Like in the solution Soheil has provided?

Comment: The timing isn't really relevant. What matters is that there are atomic transactions that either insert a new, independent `StripeTransfer` or `StripePayment`. Therefore, neither can have an enforced FK constraint to the other. With Soheil's mapping, no `StripePayment` with a non-existing `SourceTransactionId` (in `StripeTransfer`) can be inserted. Only a junction table allows establishing an enforced-integrity relationship after inserting either records independently. Of course the drawback is that there must be code that actually does that as soon as it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. you should just change the generic type in *HasPrincipalKey* and *HasForeignKey*.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StripePayment>()
        .HasOne<StripeTransfer>(t => t.StripeTransfer)
        .WithOne(t => t.StripePayment)
        .HasPrincipalKey<StripeTransfer>(p => p.SourceTransactionId)
        .HasForeignKey<StripePayment>(t => t.SourceTransactionId)
        .IsRequired(false);
```