# How insert data in to multiple tables with one to one relationship in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework-core, relationship, one-to-one

I have two tables with the details as shown here, which have a one-to-one relationship with one another.

```
public partial class Concept : AuditableWithBaseEntity<decimal>
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public decimal ConceptnodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Conceptnode Conceptnode { get; set; }
}

public partial class Conceptnode : BaseEntity<decimal>
{
    public decimal ConceptId { get; set; }
    public int Presentationorder { get; set; }

    public virtual Concept Concept { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to insert data with this code:

```
Concept targetConcept = new()
{
    Code = currTC.Code,
    Conceptnode = new Conceptnode()
                      {
                          presentationOrder = currTC.presentationOrder
                      }
};

_dbContext.Concepts.Add(targetConcept)
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I get an error:

> An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "conceptnls_fk2". The conflict occurred in database "DB_P20", The statement has been terminated.

Is there any other way to use for such scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75563429/how-do-i-create-a-one-to-one-mapping-without-using-a-foreign-key-constraint/75571095#75571095
**this link is different about your problem, but I think is useful for read.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your *mapping* and how you create your **decimal Id**, but try this.

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Concept>()
          .HasOne(t => t.Conceptnode)
          .WithOne(t => t.Concept)
          .HasForeignKey<Concept>(t => t.ConceptnodeId)
          .IsRequired(false);
  }
```

Comment: thank you.

I have established the one to one relationship between the tables using FluentAPI, problem issue when i send the data to database data EF core doesn't create record in the database.

Comment: So, please add more detail from your code.